# Recursive CTE cumulative SUM in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my query:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  Group_ID,Parent_ID,AliasName
    FROM    TEST
    WHERE   Group_ID = 153

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  t.Group_ID,t.Parent_ID,t.AliasName
    FROM    TEST t INNER JOIN
            cte r ON t.Parent_ID = r.Group_ID
)

SELECT r.Group_ID,
   r.Parent_ID,
   r.AliasName,
   C.[Count]
FROM CTE r
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
              FROM TEST V
              WHERE V.Parent_ID = r.Group_ID) C;
```

Output:

```
Group_ID    Parent_ID   AliasName   Count   
153         2           AMIG        1   
186         153         BPS         1   
187         186         IN          1   
188         187         CHE         1   
193         188         TEK         1   
194         193         COMPUTERS   1   
195         194         THINCLIENTS 0
```

Expected output:

```
Group_ID    Parent_ID   AliasName   Count   Sum    (Explanation)
153         2           AMIG        6       75      0
186         153         BPS         5       75      10
187         186         IN          4       65      10  
188         187         CHE         3       55      10
193         188         TEK         2       45      10
194         193         COMPUTERS   1       35      5
195         194         THINCLIENTS 0       30      30
```

There is a table called TblData where we store list of ID for their Respective group, If we write a query:

```
select * from tblData where group_iD=195 (It will return 30 IDs)
for group_ID=194 it will return 5 and so on. So Sum column will sum the cumulative data and display.
```

My tbldata table sample data:

```
   Declare @tblData table (Group_ID int,ID int)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (195,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (194,2)
Insert into @tblData values  (194,2)
Insert into @tblData values  (194,2)
Insert into @tblData values  (194,2)
Insert into @tblData values  (194,2)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (193,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (188,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (187,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
Insert into @tblData values  (186,1)
```

NOTE: Explanation column is just for reference.

I am finding it difficult to get the sum and count column. someone plz suggest.

Now I tried this query :

```
WITH cte AS(
        SELECT  Group_ID,Parent_ID,AliasName
        FROM    Server_Tree_Group
        WHERE   Group_ID = 153

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  t.Group_ID,t.Parent_ID,t.AliasName
        FROM    Server_Tree_Group t INNER JOIN
                cte r ON t.Parent_ID = r.Group_ID
)


SELECT r.Group_ID,
       r.Parent_ID,
       r.AliasName,
       sum(C.[Count]) over (order by group_ID desc) as count

FROM CTE r
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
                  FROM Server_Tree_Group V
                  WHERE V.Parent_ID = r.Group_ID) C
```

This query works for ID=153 when I call the Root Id which is 2 it fails.

Comment: *"I am finding it difficult to get the sum and count column. someone plz suggest."* What's wrong with `SUM` and `COUNT`? Why didn't they work? You haven't included `tblData` in your sample, so we can't help you. *(Also, it's not an `;WITH` expression, it's just `WITH`. `;` is a statement **terminator** and it goes at the end of **all** your statements, not at the start of a `WITH`/`MERGE` expression. it's not a* "beginningator"*.)*

Comment: @Larnu I got the count column in my query but I am expecting cumulative count

Comment: plz post the complete data for the Test table for which you have posted expected results.

Comment: Your sample data and query have nothing to do with each other.